# how can i create tools to canvas with jquery

Tags: jquery, html, canvas

how can i create tools to canvas with jquery so 
i want to create tools to control canvas element like rotate , resize and flip 
i fount web site do that but i can't know how they do that
the site is  :: https://gomockingbird.com/mockingbird

and i want to add listener like the example site to can show or hide tools and dClick to Edit Content as example

i try to do this

```
$('body').on('click','.art',function(){
            var rand = Math.ceil(Math.random() * 100087600);
            var canvas = loadCanvas({src:"assets/img/"+$( this ).attr("data-img"),id:'canvas_'+$(this).attr('data-name')+'_'+rand});
            //.resizable();
            //canvas.css('position','absolute');
            /*
            <div style="overflow: hidden; position: absolute; visibility: visible; z-index: 0; left: 119px; top: 134px; width: 422px; height: 115px; -webkit-transform: translateX(0px);"><canvas width="422" height="115" style="z-index: -100; overflow: hidden; position: absolute; visibility: visible; top: 0px; left: 0px; width: 422px; height: 115px;"></canvas></div>
            .('<div />',{w:10,H:10})*/
            $('#stage').prepend('<div id="div_'+$(this).attr('data-name')+'_'+rand+'" style="position: absolute"></div>');

            $('#div_'+$(this).attr('data-name')+'_'+rand).hide();
            $('#div_'+$(this).attr('data-name')+'_'+rand).prepend(canvas);
            $('#div_'+$(this).attr('data-name')+'_'+rand).show('scale');
            $('#div_'+$(this).attr('data-name')+'_'+rand).draggable({ containment: "parent" }).resizable({ containment: "parent" });
        });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you are planning to do lot of manipulation on canvas then i would recommend using [kineticjs](http://kineticjs.com/) .most of the things you are planing to do are implemented easily in [kinecticjs](http://kineticjs.com/).They have great tutorials and decent docs.Hope that helps.